chocking rights on directory with command ls -l gives total 0
I'm trying to understand why a NAS cannot be mounted. When i run this mount command i have :

mount -t cifs //10.XX.XX.XXX/Dir1 /nas -o credentials=/config/cred,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),vers=3.0


mount error(127): Key has expired
so trying to check whether destination directory is created and what rights it has. I use ls -l /nas and it gives "total 0". What does that mean ? i don't understand what's wring here

it might help if you [edit] your question with the exact mount command you are executing and details about your Linux instance. This error usually occurs because your password may have expired or need to change it and refers usually to a windoze instance. Login into the Windows Machine or Remote Desktop it. After entering your current correct credentials, you'll be prompted to change the password. Provide a new password. After the password is successfully changed, try mounting again (and it should work) See this Ubuntu Forums reference

hello, thanks for your reply. I will try to change password and try mount again. I added the mount command i used..

total 0 just means that you are listing an empty directory - in this case because the mount command failed so you are listing an empty mountpoint instead of the remote share.
